# Forms Authentication set to None, but authentication with SQL Server is still being attempted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, forms-authentication

How can I disable forms authentication? Every time I navigate to a page, the page tries to authenticate through an SQL instance on server. I have set forms authentication to none, but still no change.

> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433   -->
>
> ```
>  <system.web>
> <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" executionTimeout="3600"/>
> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
> <!--<authorization>
>   <allow users="*"/>
> </authorization>-->
> <!--<authentication mode="None">
>   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
> </authentication>-->
> <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
>   <providers>
>     <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider,
> ```
>
> System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
>   connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />

Comment: FormsAuthentication has nothing to do with SQL.  It is strictly a cookie based system.  Something else is obviously occurring that is causing a database access.  I notice you have a profile provider.. that is most likely doing database access.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I went with leaving Forms Authentication enabled, and rather setup IIS to have access rights to an instance of SQL Express installed the server. All pages work fine now.